# Emacs multi keyboard shortcut

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying to create a combination keybinding.

Here's an example:

```
(define-key my-minor-mode-map (kbd "x f") "\C-x\C-f")
```

(edit: Thanks you Stefan for pointing out the space between \C-x and \C-f.)

This however takes me to a random file and describe-key says this:

```
Macro: C-x C-f
Keyboard macro.
```

So I'm not really sure what that means.
It seems that trying to bind s to C-s doesn't work either (As well as other interactive commands like C-r and M-x).

This does work:

```
(define-key my-minor-mode-map (kbd "x f") "\M-f")
```

So basically I want to be able to run C-x C-f (find-file) without having to type 'find-file as a function itself.

In other words; I don't want this:

```
(define-key my-minor-mode-map (kbd "x f") 'find-file)
```

I hope someone could help me out with this. My emacs knowledge is very limited.

Thanks in advance.

Complete code:

```
(defvar my-minor-mode-map (make-keymap) "my-minor-mode keymap")
(define-key my-minor-mode-map (kbd "x f") "\C-x\C-f")
(define-minor-mode my-minor-mode
"My minor-mode"

t "My minor mode" 'my-minor-mode-map)
(defun my-minibuffer-setup-hook ()
    (my-minor-mode 0))
"My minor-mode"
```

Edit:

What would even be better is if I could do this:

```
(define-key my-minor-mode-map (kbd "x") "\C-x")
(define-key my-minor-mode-map (kbd "f") "\C-f")
```

And then if I would type "x f" that it would exectue "\C-x C-f" aka find file.
That way I wouldn't have to write out every possible key combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain what you believe should be happening here, but I suspect what you actually want is:

```el
(define-key my-minor-mode-map (kbd "x f") (key-binding (kbd "C-x C-f")))
```

which is the same thing as the code you said you didn't want to use:

```el
(define-key my-minor-mode-map (kbd "x f") 'find-file)
```

except that it obtains the function dynamically, based on the key binding.

p.s. It's also slightly odd that you're using a mixture of `kbd` and non-`kbd` syntax in the same form.

Answer (score 2):

`"\C-x \C-f"` has 3 elements: `C-x`, `SPC`, and `C-f`.  You probably did not mean for that space to be there.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, however I still don't get he desired result. When I use describe-key I get: Macro: C-x C-f. When I run it, it takes me to a random file. I've also noticed trying to bind s to C-s doesn't work either (As well as other interactive commands like C-r, M-x etc.